# Can't display Google+ and Facebook Like on the same line

Tags: css, facebook, twitter, facebook-like, google-plus

I have been banging my head for last many hour to get this solved but it is not working.

I want to display Facebook Like box, Twitter and Google + on one line but it displays them on different lines and just shows Facebook Like box correctly.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="likefooter">                    

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$my_base_url}{$story_url}& amp;layout=standard;&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none;  overflow:hidden; width:450px;"></iframe>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<g:plusone size="medium" annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

        </div>
```

CSS file is here:
http://www.box.net/shared/2agu4dy10mb4y3pj7e1m

Comment: You should probably add the relevant parts of your CSS in the question. The document viewer on the site you're linking to is horrible for browsing code. But please only add the parts that matter, so people don't have to read all of it.

Answer (score 4):

please try

```
    <div class="likefooter">                    

    <div style="float:left;"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$my_base_url}{$story_url}& amp;layout=standard;&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none;  overflow:hidden; width:450px;"></iframe></div>  

    <div style"float:left;"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>  

   <div style="float:left;"><g:plusone size="medium" annotation="inline"></g:plusone></div>  

     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. wrap the elements in `<li>`
2. style them `display:inline`
3. omit the `data-width` attribute from the `<div class="fb-like">` tag.

css:

```
ul.social { list-style: none outside none; }
ul.social > li { display:inline; }
```

html:

```
<ul class="social">
  <li>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>{{ facebook SDK script }}</script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="{{ your URL }}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count"  data-show-faces="false"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <{{ twitter button }}>
    <script>{{ twitter javascript }}</script>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like your solution - no inline styles here. Just edit typo - "social" in css. And you can add in `ul.social > li {vertical-align: top;}` since FB is going misplaced down, compared with other social buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The solution may be far easier -- the default width of the Facebook button is 250, open up the html and reduce it to 75 or so.

Answer (score 0):

iFrame is a block-level element by default. You'll have to make the display:inline in the CSS. 
g:plusone might be one too, but I've never heard of that tag.

Comment: great .. so I just add this property in CSS? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put padding-top:5px; on the one that is on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

If CSS tweaks do not help make sure that your document is not rendering in quirks mode. Sometimes quirks rendering mode causes the +1 button to display on the next line.

You can check for this using Firefox webmaster tools or try tossing your page into a validator (http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure there aren't too many errors.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
    <table cellpadding="4" style="width: auto !important; float: none !important; margin: 8px 0;">
                <tr>
<td><img src="http://gnosisarts.com/home/images/fancy_g2.jpg" width="75" border="0" alt="Gnosis Media Group Internet PR Firm" /></td>
                    <!-- Google +1 Section Starts -->
                    <td>
                        <g:plusone size="tall" href="http://gnosisarts.com/home/Internet_PR"></g:plusone>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            (function() {
                                var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                            })();
                        </script>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Google +1 Section Ends -->

                    <!-- Twitter Button Section Starts -->
                    <td>
                        <!-- async trick from http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/40-xhtml-strict-tweet-button-and-facebook-like-button -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                        (function() {
                                document.write('<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="gnosisarts" data-url="http://gnosisarts.com/home/Internet_PR">Tweet</a>');
                                var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'), s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
                                s.type = 'text/javascript';
                                s.async = true;
                                s.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                                s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
                        })();
                        //]]>
                        </script>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Twitter Button Section Ends -->

                                        <!-- LinkedIn Button Section Starts -->
                    <td>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                        (function() {
                                var e = document.createElement('script');
                                e.type="text/javascript"; e.async = true;
                                e.src = 'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js';
                                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
                        })();
                        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://gnosisarts.com/home/Internet_PR" data-counter="top"></script>
                    </td>
                    <!-- LinkedIn Button Section Ends -->

                    <!-- Like Button Section Starts -->
                    <td>
                        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fgnosisartsmediagroup&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=65&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=65" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:65px; height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Like Button Section Ends -->

            </tr>
            </table>
```

### #

Just change the social share URLs and other params to your own sites accordingly.

Eric